# How to write multiple OpenTSDB data points into CnosDB?

Tags: opentsdb, cnosdb

I am helping my end users migrating some data interface from OpenTSDB to CnosDB and following [this doc here](https://docs.cnosdb.com/en/v2.3/reference/rest_api.html#list-of-interfaces).I could write one data point per quest as follows:

```
curl -i -u "myUsername:myPassword" -XPOST "http://localhost:8902/api/v1/opentsdb/write?db=example" -d 'test 1666165200290401000 1 host=web01 interface=eth0'
```

How to write multiple data points in **ONE POST request** so to make best use of the batch writing optimization?